# How to install OpenLayers plugin in QGIS1.8

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 on Windows 7 (32-bit) but am unable to install the OpenLayers plugin.  The Python plugins menu does not include OpenLayers on the plugin list.  Can it be somehow added manually?

Comment: Openlayers plugin is now part of the official Qgis plugin repository with version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

Until Openlayers plugin is incorporated in the official rep, you have to add the sourcepole repo manually by adding
http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml
in the second tab. And make sure it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Select fetch python plugins/repositories/add/enter name "sourcepole", url "http://build.sourcepole.ch/qgis/plugins.xml"/select enabled/ok

http://qgismalaysia.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-openlayer-plugin-on-new.html